# Failed to connect to hadoop cluster when accessing file from pyspark

Tags: hadoop, pyspark

I'm running the following code:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("basicRegressionUbuntu").setMaster("spark://MyCUSTOMIP:7077")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://MYHADOOPMASTERNODE:8020/sampleData/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv")
```

It throws the following:

```
16/03/25 10:01:11 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:42939
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:42939
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: /10.0.2.15:42939
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

I know that file path exists because when I SSH into MYHADOOPMASTERNODE and do an `hdfs dfs -ls /sampleData/` it shows me the fille.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: if your cluster is running yarn then change the setmaster to "yarn" and try. Not sure why you have spark:// for master as spark-master on  a yarn based cluster would be the yarn resource manager which spark would pick up from YARN_CONF_DIR.

Comment: @urug: you mean ".setMaster("yarn://MyCUSTOMIP:7077")? That won't work it can't parse the Master URL?

Comment: .setMaster("yarn")

Comment: If I'm submitting a job to a remote cluster -- and all I have is spark installed -- then it won't know the address of the master node.

Comment: what is this ip address 10.0.2.15 ? or in other words, where is your driver starting? seems to me a problem of instantiating/connecting to your spark driver rather than HDFS related problem